# Tableau accessing production database or intermediary

Tags: tableau-api

We are currently looking into using tableau for analysis of app user data.

Some concerns were raised in my company about connecting tableau to our production database.

- Security: We are not happy to share sensitive user data with tableau.
- Database load: tableau queries may have a negative effect on the performance of our production database.

The idea came up to create a intermediary database. A script would regularly pull data from our production database and insert it into the intermediary database.

This may also make it easier to access data from our redis, elasticseatch, ??? and our main database in postgres.

Does anyone have experience with such a intermediary database? Is this common practice?

Comment: an intermediary database is more commonly called a data warehouse. It can buffer queries that would impact production and can merge, join or reformat data to make it easier to analyse (or remove sensitive information not required for analysis).

Comment: This is very common practice and probably best practice to create tables or views that contain only the relevant information that you will pull from to build your dashboards.

If you are only using Tableau Desktop and Tableau Server, there won't be any "sharing" of data with Tableau as these are only locally managed. Tableau Online is the only Tableau hosted offering I can think of where your data would end up on their servers.

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful. Views may also be a good idea. Should we be concerned about performance when using views (as they are effectively using the same resources) or are such queries negligible? The idea behind our strategy was to duplicate almost everything (hundreds of gigabytes). Was wondering if this duplication is common in data warehouses or creating views?

Comment: @MichaelEttlinger Views might have a significant impact on performance if they are used a lot (every request has to query the live production system). If they are not viewed or updated often and are not individually burdensome this might not be a problem. But best practice is to create a *separate* data warehouse with the data you need for analysis as this means however much analysis you do you won't impact the production system.